# Antonym of permission

Tags: word-request, nouns, antonyms

What noun describes the act of forbidding something?

Just as 'permission' means allowing certain activity, is there a noun that states the opposite?

In particular, I'm looking for one that states 'disallowance' (if you allow me to make up this kind of word) a'priori, unlike 'denial', 'refusal', 'rejection', 'refusal', which all apply to a request: Imagine a grassy square where kids like to play soccer, disturbing people in nearby houses. If they ask "Can we play soccer here?" - "No, you can't" is a refusal. A sign on the grass "No playing soccer allowed" doesn't qualify as such though - it's there before intent to play even appears.

Comment: I considered [restriction](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/restriction) and [limitation](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/limitation) but those would both imply that there was somewhere where you *could* play, just that it's not here, or else that you can play here *sometimes*, or that you can play *some games* but not football.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The closest word that I can think of that has this meaning is **[prohibition](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english-cobuild-learners/prohibition)**:

> If a law or someone in authority prohibits something, they forbid it or make it illegal.

Comment: Or in some contexts, [**ban**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/ban) (noun *and* verb).

Comment: Or in some contexts, "bar".

Answer (score 2):

There is also

> [***proscription***](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/proscription) : a decree that prohibits something

from [*proscribe*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/proscribe)

> ```
>  To prohibit; forbid.
> ```
>
> *There was virtually no moral or legal **proscription** against drinking until after the War of Independence.* - [A Renegade History of the United States](http://books.simonandschuster.com/Renegade-History-of-the-United-States/Thaddeus-Russell/9781416571094)

Answer (score 0):

*Forbiddance*: the act of forbidding. [MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/forbiddance), [FD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Forbiddance), [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/forbiddance), [Reference.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/forbiddance).

Comment: Accurate, but esoteric: occurs 58 times in [GLoWBE](http://corpus2.byu.edu/glowbe/?c=glowbe&q=31559718), not at all in [COCA](http://corpus.byu.edu/coca/?c=coca&q=31559729), and just 10 times in [BNC](http://corpus.byu.edu/bnc/?c=bnc&q=31559731).

Answer (score 0):

Impermissible is the closest to the word "permission" itself, though it is not a noun.

Impermissive seems like it could work but it really is the opposite of the word permissive, not permission. The words are related, but do not have the same meaning.